# searching for a group of keywords in multiple fields using lucene

Tags: java, mysql, lucene, innodb, full-text-search

these are the columns of my database indexed by lucene:

```
category_name / sub_category_name / classification_name / item_name / supplier
```

then sample data are as follows:

```
ALUMINUM / ORDINARY / 3" / CHINA ALUMINUM / <BLANK>
ALUMINUM / ORDINARY / 4" / USA ALUMINUM / <BLANK>
ALUMINUM / SPECIAL / 1" / PHL ALUMINUM / JKL MANUFACTURERS
ALUMINUM / PLAIN / 1" / CANADA ALUMINUM / ABC COMPANY
ALUMINUM / SPECIAL / 3"A / CHINA ALUMINUM / DEF INC
```

i want my user to enter a group of keywords in the search bar, search this keywords in all of the columns and will display specific results. such as whenever the user searches for

```
 "ALUMINUM 3"A CHINA"
```

it will just display this record:

```
ALUMINUM / SPECIAL / 3"A / CHINA ALUMINUM / DEF INC
```

will there by a lucene query for that? i use java as my main language, and mysql for my database. my database storage engine is InnoDB

Answer (score 0):

If your searches go across all columns, then index them all as one field. Then the user just types in their query and you won't need to do anything.

Comment: so what type of lucene query will i be using then?

Comment: ...Whatever kind you want? What do you mean?

Comment: got what you meant already. i used queryparser for parsing and it worked well. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

org.apache.lucene.queryParser.**MultiFieldQueryParser** is designed for such case.